npx expo run:android causes a failed to install. its trying to install test only apk
I've built an app and i'm trying to incorporate react-native-google-signin. Which requires me to build and run the app instead of using expo go
However, when i try to run npx expo run:android, after build successful it throws this error
Error: adb: failed to install C:\Fetch\fetch-app-redesign\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: Failed to install test-only apk. Did you forget to add -t?] 

I've searched for a solution for hours and could not find any

Had the same issue! I wanted to incorporate Agora which will not work with Expo Go, trying to build it and have almost the same error with adb. I think the problem was something to do with not being able to put files on my connected device.
I am now using EAS to create development builds remotely rather than locally, and not running into this issue. You can see how to use EAS submit here, they show all the instructions with pictures. More information on building with EAS can be found here.
